# Are there any words to replace the word "improve" in the phrase "improve your efficiency"?

Tags: synonyms

I am writing an article about myself and I want to write "I need to improve my efficiency to speed up my progress." But I want to use a different word than improve to represent the similar meaning because I've already written "improve" for several times in the previous sections of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just

> I need to be more efficient in order to progress faster.

"Improve my  efficiency" and "speed up my progress" both sound awkward and too wordy to me.